# Why does my except block not catch my error here?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to access a dictionary at the key where it doesn't exist so I put a try except block around it and add the key during the except. It doesn't catch the `KeyError` like it's supposed to. I get a `KeyError` during the if statement in my try block. I made a workaround but want to know what is going on here.  Sorry if this is not enough to go on let me know if you need more info this is my first post sorry if its bad.

`get_test_ids_map()` returns:

```
{'1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], '2': [1, 2, 3, 6, 7], '3': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}
```

````
        student,test_taken = item
        student_courses_map = {}
        student_courses = set()
        for row in tests_df.itertuples(index=False):
            id,course_id,weight = row
            if id in test_taken:
                try:
                    if str(course_id) not in student_courses_map[student]:
                        student_courses.add(course_id)
                        student_courses_map.update({student : student_courses})
                except KeyError:
                    student_courses_map[student] = f'{course_id}'
                    student_courses.add(course_id)```
````

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We cannot run the above without getting any number of `NameError`s from undefined names like `item`, `tests_df`, `test_taken`, etc.

Comment: There's still an error because the error is likely happening in your `except` block. This looks like a case where you should probably use the `dict.get()` method. [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_dictionary_get.asp)

Comment: I tried this get a TypeError NoneType.

Comment: Here is the repo. Not sure how it will behave on your system though.
https://github.com/TrintinAffleck/Csv-to-Json/tree/main/LeetCode%20Practise/Py_Practise_Env/Scripts

Comment: You can see my workaround on there just remove the if else around the try block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try use `element in dict.get(key, [])` to avoid check the `KeyError`, like @BeRT2me said. The code will be :

```
student_courses_map = {}
student_courses = set()
for row in tests_df.itertuples(index=False):
    _id,course_id,weight = row
    if _id in test_taken:
        if str(course_id) not in student_courses_map.get(student,[]):    
            ...
        else:
            ...
```

Comment: Bro, you are a genius. I was trying to find a way to remove my exception blocks and this solves both problems. Thank you! Will be using .get() from now on so I can pass in a default.